# Is there any register to check if neon is supported on a armv8 machine?

Tags: assembly, arm64, neon, armv8

I was researching and I found this register `ID_AA64ZFR0_EL1` it checks if SVE is supported. "SVE Feature ID register 0". I was wondering if there is any register which I can use to check if Neon is supported.
If not, is there any other way I can check it **using assembly**?

Comment: One of the processor feature registers has a nibble for that.  But unless the OS lets you, you won't be able to read it.

Comment: @fuz do you know which register? I am not using any OS, I am working on a pre OS application.

Comment: Try `ID_AA64PFR0_EL1`.  You're looking for the *AdvSIMD* bits.

Comment: @fuz thank you very much! This will work

Comment: @fuz: This question should be tagged [tag:arm64], right?  Is `ID_AA64ZFR0_EL1` even readable in 32-bit ARM mode?  If it is, I suppose we should also / instead tag [tag:arm]?  I'm guessing from the AA64 in the name, it's specific to AArch64 mode?  Or is it actually specific to ARMv8 and readable in both modes?

Comment: @PeterCordes, if I am not wrong, this question is tagged `assembly`, `arm64`, `neon`,`armv8`

Comment: It is now, after I edited the tags.  I was asking fuz if I should also or instead have tagged arm.  (Is NEON / AdvSIMD not guaranteed available in AArch64?  I thought it might have been baseline like SSE2 for x86-64.)

Comment: @PeterCordes The ARMv8 ARM says that it can be left out but only for special applications.  You are not going to find an application-class ARMv8 chip without NEON.